# Using Class Modules to Store a Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I've found a few helpful related questions, but I can't seem to pull it all together. I'm trying to move some dictionaries that are in my Standard Module over into their own Class Modules; however, I can't figure out how to get around the fact that I don't want to 're-initialize' the dictionary each time I create a new class object.

Prior to trying to put the dictionaries into a class of their own, I have them being created in my standard module via a `Private Function` that returns an Object. One reason I'm trying to move them into a class is to allow me to use something other than a simple `String` as the Key, so I'm going to have more complicated `Property Get` where I pass in a different class object and check various items in a specific order to determine if the key exists in the dictionary or not. I have failed miserably thus far.

Standard Module Code:

```
Sub Main()
Dim TestVar As New clsDictionary
TestVar.ID("First") = "Something"

Set TestVar = New clsDictionary
TestVar.ID("Second") = "Something else"

Debug.Print TestVar.ID("First")
```

Class Module:

```
Option Explicit
Private dID As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
If dID Is Nothing Then
    Set dID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End If
End Sub

Public Property Get ID(Key As String) As String
If dID.Exists(Key) Then
    ID = "Exists in Dictionary"
Else
    ID = "Does not exist in Dictionary"
End If

End Property
Public Property Let ID(Key As String, Value As String)
    dID(Key) = Value
End Property
```

Comment: `Set TestVar = New clsDictionary` replaced the original class instance that you added the First key to.

Comment: This I realized, but for some reason reading it might have just been a eureka moment. Rather than `Set TestVar = New clsDictionary` - I'm guessing I can just go directly into `TestVar.ID("Second") = "Something else"`? And I still had it open, so I tested that...wow that was a dumb mistake

Comment: No need to check if `dID` is nothing when the class is initialized, it's guaranteed to be nothing. Just create it directly.

Answer (score 0):

As Rory quite astutely pointed out in the comments, any time that I call `New clsDictionary` I'm going to be initializing a new class instance and in effect an entirely new dictionary object.

Knowing that, my Class Code now actually creates the entire dictionary when it is first initialized which is pretty much all of the code from the `Private Function` I was using originally. My standard code at that point should really only call `New clsDictionary` when the dictionary needs to be populated.